# MBProgressHUD, Library not loaded?

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Yesterday, everything OK.
But today I get this error when I try attach Game_App to My IPhone, any help:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/MBProgressHUD.framework/MBProgressHUD
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/.../Game_App
Incompatible library version: Game_App requires version 1.0.0 or later, but MBProgressHUD provides version 0.9.1
```

Podfile: `pod 'MBProgressHUD'`

When I run pod update and pod install: `Using MBProgressHUD (0.9.1)`